# ROS Answers SE migration: Rosrun error

Tags: ros, rosrun, bag-to-pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quick question-

I'm trying to create a working subscriber to grab pointcloud data from my .bag file. 1. First I created a subscribe.cpp file in workspace/package_name. 2. Then I figured I'd use bag_to_pcd in pcl_ros to get all the pointcloud2 messages out of the .bag file and saved as .pcd files. (Is this necessary?) 3. Later, I can do the calculations I need to on each individual pointcloud.

Right now I'm having trouble with step #2. I did "rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd test.bag /sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 pcd_dir" - I'm getting this error:

[code]Creating directory pcd_dir
Saving recorded sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 messages on topic /sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 to pcd_dir
[ERROR] [1362462945.838294912]: Frame id /base_link does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /tx90/flange exists with parent /tx90/base_link.
Frame /tx90/base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.[/code]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57065/rosrun-error/) by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This solved the answer to my problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/56301/frame-id-base_link-does-not-exist-when-extracting-bag-to-pcd/

Apparently doing "rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/sr/pointcloud2_raw" the is the same as using bag_to_pcd, and there is some error with the bag_to_pcd function.

---

Originally posted by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) with karma: 57 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-03-05**:
It's better that you edit your question rather than posting an answer